# Moderator election vote counts aren't showing up for me

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, moderator-elections

When I click a candidate's score in the moderator election primary, I see this:

[image: "An error occurred during vote count fetch"]

This happens for every candidate on SU, but does not affect SO, regardless of whether or how I've voted on a particular candidate.

Here's my <del>theory</del> wild speculation about the cause: I suspect that the vote count split logic was copied directly from the regular post code. Since I only have 655 SU rep, I would be ineligible to see the split. But if this is the reason, then I shouldn't be allowed to click on the number at all, to match the behavior seen on regular posts.

In short: if this isn't by design, please fix the bug; if it is, please don't change the cursor to a hand icon when it's over mod election vote counts or allow the number to be clickable for <1k rep users.

Comment: Works fine here, can't seem to reproduce the error. So I guess you're right with the rep limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was raised on Meta Stack Overflow ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/who-can-split-the-votes-in-the-primary-election)) and it has been reported that it will be fixed in the next deployment (I don't know when this is, presumably "soon"). In otherwords it should be fixed shortly.

For the record, I can reproduce this issue on Stack Overflow (where I have ~500rep)